# apache2+mod_wsgi with multiple django process in each host name

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I want to run multiple django project with multiple host name.

If use come from www.momsy.org, it goes to /var/web/momsy.git.org
other if come from www.momsy.net, it goes to /var/web/momsy.git.net

This is to log and analyze where he/she came from.

So, following does not work because [WSGIPythonPath cannot occur within  section].

But I can't use http.conf because i need 'servername' variable.

How Can I solve this problem?

> ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
>           ServerName www.momsy.org

```
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/web/momsy.git.kr/momsy/wsgi.py                             
    WSGIPythonPath /home/web/momsy.git.kr                                              

    <Directory  /home/web/momsy.git.kr/momsy>                                          
    <Files wsgi.py>                                                                    
            Order deny,allow                                                           
            Allow from all                                                             
    </Files>                                                                           
    </Directory>
```

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use daemon mode, delegate each Django instance to a separate set of processes, and set python-path against each daemon process group as required for each. See:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

Otherwise set the sys.path in the WSGI script file and not in the Apache configuration.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango